# How To Find Out The Reason Behind A Hung Application

Tags: networking, performance, lan, client-server

We have a product which has two divisions one is workstation edition which contains only UI and other is Server edition contains both UI and database part.We do have lot of systems running on Different set up and networks.Out of one network client system UI hangs. I verified  in Taskmanager its taking more CPU and Memory.So i desided to forcibly close the application. Again i restarted but after sometime  again hanged. But i am sure this is something related to network setup,or host file manupulations

When i checked host file resides in the server i can see a lot of entries

```
117.192.41.192  leafsp3                       sp3                       # Victor
117.192.41.193  msn-leafsp4 msnfsp4                    # Victor
```

Here "msn-leafsp4" is client system name , but again i am seeing an entry in that line "msnfsp4" , do i need to move it in to comments(#) .I beleive this guy Victor is working different netwrok may be for some testing he did like that. So my question is other than IP address and Hostnames all should be moved in to comments right?

What are the other possible checks i need to look for finding the slowness? IF same name with different IP address will make this kind of behaviour? Do i need to disable any ports?

Comment: @Dave M Do you feel anything wrong in host file

Comment: if the router has any issues any driver software are out of date, will that make any issues?

Answer (score 1):

If a process is using more CPU time & memory, it's highly unlikely that the cause is a network configuration issue, however if the application is poorly coded then the hang could be due to repeatedly trying to connect to an IP address.

To address your specific hosts-file-related concern, if a hosts file has multiple IP addresses listed with the same name, the first will be used (this can be inferred from [this ancient microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751132.aspx) which states that the file is parsed as needed in a linear fashion). Having multiple names mapped to the same IP address, as is the case with your sample hosts file, is also fine - for example, actual domain names in use by the wider internet can point to the same IP address (and this is quite common).

With regards to the odd formatting of your hosts file, that is definitely non-standard. What you need to change it to will depend on what hostnames are expected by various different applications. If I was you, I would include both sets of names, because I don't know which are in use:

```
117.192.41.192  leafsp3                        # Victor
117.192.41.192  sp3                            # Victor
117.192.41.193  msn-leafsp4                    # Victor  
117.192.41.193  msnfsp4                        # Victor
```

I'm not sure what you mean by disabling ports exactly as I've never heard of it.

In terms of other troubleshooting, check whether other applications are working fine, and if they are, just wait. I assume you're on Windows, so you can use the [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to keep an eye on whether a process is reading/writing to the disk/network (if you turn on the appropriate columns) which is nice to reassure yourself that something is happening. Often the problem is simply that the application is performing a calculation instead of drawing updates to the screen (to put it simply for the benefit of later people reading this), and when the calculation finishes then the window will stop "not responding" and everything will go back to normal.

If all else fails, complain to whoever supports the software. It sounds like an enterprise type of product so there should be appropriate channels to get this kind of thing fixed.

Comment: sorry both has different network name, i corrected ips. So you mean "117.192.41.193  msn-leafsp4 msnfsp4" is not a big issue.you mean here some other systems are treating this ip as name msn-leafsp4 and some are msnfsp4 rite?

Comment: `117.192.41.193 msn-leafsp4` followed by `117.192.41.193 msnfsp4` on the next line would not be an issue. If they are on the same line, I suspect only the first would be recognized (`msn-leafsp4` in your example). And if, in your comment, by "systems" you mean "applications", then yes: some applications may try to connect to `msn-leafsp4` and others may connect to `msnfsp4`, and that would be normal - but whether that is actually the case depends on the applications & their configuration.

Comment: 117.192.41.193 system which has application hung so based on your input lot of applications are interacting with that system, so possibly that also will lead to a hung??

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment. It's possible that an overloaded system could lead to a slowdown which looks like a hang, but I never intended to imply that a lot of applications were interacting with `117.192.41.193`. Really, this is likely complete guesswork and you're much better off contacting the developer of the application if you truly believe it is not functioning as designed.